# why log(n)! isn't zero?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I am going to prove that log(n)! is growing faster than log(n!)

I have wondered that why the log(n)! isn't zero for n∈N.

Because I think that log(1) is zero so all following numbers after multiplying the result will become zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just thought I'd point this out. In mathematics, `0!` is defined as 1. Since `log(1)=0` it follows that `log(1)!=1`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log(n!)` is not zero because:

```
log(m * n) == log(m) + log(n)
log(2!) = log(2 * 1) = log(2) + log(1) = log(2) + 0
```

In terms of `log(n)!` you can ignore the `log(1)` part. Take for example a binary search tree with one node, its root. The search for a value with a binary search tree is `log(n)` where n is the number of nodes. So with only a root the search should be zero according to the computation you do, however it is still one, because you have to check the root value. In this sense you can assume `log(1) == 1` to avoid confusion.

Comment: does lg(3)! means lg(1) * lg(2) * lg(3)?

Comment: @Liang-YuPan Hmm I read your question wrong. In terms of computer operations you can ignore the log(1) I will update the answer with why.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics your answer is 99% unrelated to the question, even with the edit.

Comment: @icepack The question is why multiplying by zero which is the result of log(1) doesn't make the entire log(n)! complexity zero, rather than generally on what complexity means. So the second part of the answer is related IMO, the first one as I said was produced by me misreading the question.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics Exactly. And you brought an example, and not a good one, and haven't given any explanation regarding the meaning of function growth and *why* log(1) isn't important for it

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't calculate the expression for `n` that equals to some constant. In order to prove that function `f` grows faster than function `g`, you need to show that for `n` that goes to infinity the value of `f` will be larger than the value of `g`.

Comment: why should ignore lg1 for small constant? I still cannot understand.

Comment: Because that's not related to the order of growth of the function. You're actually seeking a derivative, i.e. a change in the function value when `n` increases. Moreover, your 2 functions aren't even defined in the same range - log(n)! isn't defined for n=0, for example.